# How do we check Twitter Bootstrap radio buttons using Laravel Dusk?

Tags: laravel, testing, webdriver, laravel-dusk, facebook-php-webdriver

According to [twitter bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms), this is how we do a radio:

```
<div class="radio">
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
```

And this is my code:

```
$browser->click('#menu-reports')
        ->waitForText('Users')
        ->click('#menu-reports-users')
        ->radio('sitesActive', '2')
        ->radio('includeDisabled', '2')
        ->radio('includeNonCertifiable', '2')
        ->press('Apply')
        ->waitForText('Showing 0 to 0 of 0 entries')
;
```

With the input inside the label tag. But the problem is that Dusk (actually Facebook Webdriver) is not able to find it this way. It keeps raising:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible
```

To make it work I have put the input outside the label, but then, of course, the boostrap radio does not show as it should anymore.

```
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" id="optionsRadios1" value="option1" checked>
  <label>
    Option one is this and that&mdash;be sure to include why it's great
  </label>
</div>
```

Does not work using IDs either:

Not even setting an ID to the input:

```
<input 
   type="radio" 
   name="sitesActive" 
   id="sitesActive3" 
   value="2"
>
```

And trying to select it this way:

```
->radio('#sitesActive3', '2')
```

The problem is that Dusk (Webdriver) cannot even see the element in the page, as this simple like fails the exact same way:

```
$browser->waitFor('#sitesActive3');
```

Resulting in:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\TimeOutException: Waited 5 seconds for selector [#sitesActive3].
```

And that happens every time I have a form with an input with a label surrounding it, if I take the input out of the label, it works. But that's not as simple with radios, as it was with some other inputs, radios.

This is a properly coded radio:

[image]

This is a radio with the input outside the label tag:

[image]

So, how are you doing this?

Answer (score 4):

My form has a radio button. This how I checked it.

> userCreate.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Gender</label>
            <div>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="m">Male
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" id="gender" name="gender" value="f">Female
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CreateUserTest.php**

```
class CreateUserTest extends DuskTestCase
{

    public function  testCreateForm()
    {
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) {
            $browser->visit('/user/create')
                ->radio('#gender', 'm')
                ->click('button[type="submit"]')
                ->assertSee('Successfully created user.');
        });
    }
}
```

This works for me. I think this will help you.

Comment: This seems incorrect because you've set `id="gender"` to multiple elements on the same page, which breaks the HTML rule that `id` must be unique.

Comment: Should not have multiple id attributes

Answer (score 2):

simplest way is to click on the parent

```
$el = $this->resolver->resolveForRadioSelection($field, $value);
$el = $el->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath(".."));
$el->click();
```

Since the radio is not visible dusk cannot click on it

You may create a trait like the following if you are using bootstrap in your project

```
trait BootstrapInteraction
{
    /**
     * Undocumented variable
     * @var \Laravel\Dusk\ElementResolver $resolver
     */
    public   $resolver;
    public function radioB($field, $value)
    {
        /**
         * @var RemoteWebElement $el
         */
        $radio = $this->resolver->resolveForRadioSelection($field, $value);
        // click on parent
        $el = $radio->findElement(WebDriverBy::xpath(".."));
        $el->click();
        // if not selected click on label 
        if (!$radio->isSelected()) {
            $el = $el->findElement(WebDriverBy::cssSelector("label"));
            $el->click();
        }

        PHPUnit::assertTrue(
            $radio->isSelected(),
            "Not able to select Radio [{$field}] within value [{$value}]."
        ); 

        return $this;
    }
```

Comment: This is the best answer imho. The $el = $browser etc. worked like a charm, straight out the box. However, @Pascal, i couldn't implement your suggested trait method. I created the Trait and added use Trait inside file and class. I access the Dusk browser instance via: $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) { $browser->radioB($field, $value)->click(); } but am getting Call to undefined method [radioB]. How do i ref browser instance and trait method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you use this trait? I guess you need to add it to the Browser? Not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

You may not be happy to edit your views for the sake of your test script but if you are open to that, what about adding a class to the

```
<input type="radio" ... >
```

and then using

```
        ->click('.yourClass')
```

in your Dusk test?

Comment: Would be odd, because I would have to add a class for every radio `.myRadioClass1; .myRadioClass2`, but I tried something like that using ids: `<radio id='radio1'>`, and doing `->click('#radio1')`, and it did not work

Comment: I tried the class thing and it seemed to work - but you're right, adding a separate class to each element could be annoying. I'll look forward to seeing what other suggestions crop up.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dusk docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/dusk#using-forms) say:

> To "select" a radio button option, you may use the `radio` method. Like many other input related methods, a full CSS selector is not required. If an exact selector match can't be found, Dusk will search for a radio with matching `name` and `value` attributes: `$browser->radio('version', 'php7');`

In my case, Dusk was working fine for *most* of my radio buttons, but it would *not* work for:

`->radio('Field728', 'Know it\'s what anyone committed to this dream would do if she found a great program that features a proven process and supportive community')`

I also tried using double-quotes, but that didn't work either. (Maybe the value is too long? I don't know.)

**So instead I did this:**

`->radio('#Field728_0', true)//this is the specific ID of the first radio button of this group`